# How does Zynga notify a user e.g. "Friend 1, Friend 2 and 5 others have been playing Poker. Play now"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-canvas

I was mid way through building an app, when I realized that a core part of the app I was planning to build (an event notifier), wouldn't work as event invites sent via the Facebook API do not show as a notifications.

**This is the notification I got:**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SCFZr.png]

It's not a notification for an event of course, but I don't know what other API methods invoke a user notification (or could invoke one).

If anyone could let me know the API method they're using, I'd be very grateful. (I'm thinking it's perhaps because they use a canvas app, while I was planning on building a web app).

Answer (score 1):

It's a user-to-user request, which is called an *invite* if the user it’s send to hasn’t used the app yet. For apps in category *games* it shows up as „have been playing”, for other apps it just says „john doe sent you a request in *xy*”

How to send them via your app, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: But I don't see how "John, James and 5 others have been playing Texas Holdem" would be a user initiated request. It's not like they personally invited me to play a game, and Zynga filled in the content of the request.

I get requests in the format "John Doe sent you a request" from Zynga's Texas Hold'em all the time as well.